# track mouse down, keyboard events done on application

Tags: drag-and-drop, mouselistener, keyboard-hook

Is there any sample application available with which I can hook into another application.
Detect control clicks on the application
Detect keyboard operations on the application.
Detecting drag drop being performed.

At the same time i could unhook from the application any time.

Basically performing this operation to create an intellisense about what are usual operations done by the user.

So whenever user performs any operation, the tracer comes to know and traces the behavior in a file.

Want to see in C#

Answer (score 0):

I think under Windows messages are sent between Windows. You can see this with http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa231779(v=vs.60).aspx . Not sure if this is what you need.